# How do I mount a ssh folder in linux from a script?

Tags: linux, mount, sshfs

I already have sshfs installed and I know how to mount the drive, but when I try to automatically supply the password it doesn't do anything different.

```
eric@MAVERICK:~$ sshfs ericfoss@192.168.0.200:/home/ericfoss/Downloads Downloads/folder/ < pass.txt
eric@192.168.0.200's password: 
eric@MAVERICK:~$
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You should look into [public key-based SSH authentication](http://www.debuntu.org/ssh-key-based-authentication) such that you don't need to supply a password to log into the 192.168.0.200 machine.

Basically, you'd run `ssh-keygen` on the MAVERICK machine as "eric" and then copy the contents of the `~.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file that's created into

> /home/ericfoss/.ssh/authorized_keys

on the 192.168.0.200 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a newline (\n) in the file you are supplying (pass.txt) after the actual password.

If you type it on the command line you also supply a newline you see.